# How to find the inverse of a function in the neighborhood of a point at which the derivative is invertible

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

According to Rudin,

> The inverse function theorem states, roughly speaking, that a continuously differentiable mapping $f$ is invertible in a neighborhood of any point $x$ at which the linear transformation $f'(x)$ is invertible.

Given a function $f$, how do you find the inverse around the point? In a problem similar but not identical to my homework,

let $f=(f_1,f_2)$ be the mapping from $R^2$ into $R^2$ given by $f_1(x,y)=e^xcos(y)$, $f_2(x,y)=e^xsiny$.
Put $a=(0,\frac{π}{3})$, $b=f(a)$. 
Let $g$ be the continuous inverse of f, defined in a neighborhood of b, such that $g(b)=a$. Find an explicit formula for g and calculate $f'(a)$ and $g'(b)$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez yes. I am trying to do problem 18

Comment: @GuachoPerez  a friend and I spent a good hour or so on 9.18 yesterday

Answer (score 1):

In general, it cannot be done. For instance, if $f$ is the mapping from $\Bbb R$ to itself given by 
$$
f(x) = x^5 + x + 1
$$
then near $x = 2, f(x) = 35$, there's a well-defined inverse...but you're not going to be able to write it down explicitly in terms of things like square roots, etc.

But more generally, for a function from 2-space to itself, say
$$
f(x, y) = (2x + 3y, 3x - y)
$$
you can write
$$
(u, v) = (2x + 3y, 3x - y)
$$
so that
$$
u = 2x + 3y\\
v = 3x - y
$$
and then you try to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. For this example, you might multiply the equations by $3$ and $2$ respectively to get
$$
3u = 6x + 9y\\
2v = 6x - 2y
$$
and then subtract to get
$$
3u - 2v = 11 y
$$
whence
$$
y = \frac{3u - 2v}{11},
$$
and you can do something similar for $x$.

The tools you use (like my choice to multiply by 3 and 2) will depend on the equations given, and you have to guess what'll allow you to eliminate one variable or the other.